# Matrix Expression from String

Tags: python, matrix, simulation, sympy

Context: I'm doing a bunch of simulations that require me to implement different Hamiltonians. These Hamiltonians are just matrices, built out of Kronecker products of some common elements, with some prefactors that I have to calculate based on the system parameters. E.g, using ⊗ for the Kronecker product

H = w1(a,b,c) * sigmax ⊗ I + w2(x,y,z)*I ⊗ sigmay

I was hoping I could make a simple parser that could read in the values of a,b,c,x,y,z and an expression for the Hamiltonian and construct the necessary matrix. Sympy seems like an obvious candidate, but I can't get a matrix expression to build using strings.

```
from sympy import symbols,Matrix,MatrixSymbol
from sympy.physics import msigma
from sympy.physics.quantum import TensorProduct
w1,w2 = symbols('w1 w2')
X1 = MatrixSymbol('X1',4,4)
X2 = MatrixSymbol('X2',4,4)
x = msigma(1)
x_1 = TensorProduct(eye(2),x)
x_2 = TensorProduct(x,eye(2))
exp = w1*X1 + w2*X2
exp.subs([(w1,0.5),(w2,2),(X1,x_1),(X2,x_2)]).as_explicit()
```

will work. But, trying

```
exp = MatrixExpr('w1*X1+w2*X2')
```

or

```
exp = MatrixExpr(sympify('w1*X1+w2*X2'))
```

or even

```
exp = sympify('w1*X1 + w2*X2')
exp.subs([(w1,0.5),(w2,2),(X1,x_1),(X2,x_2)])
```

won't.
It also won't work if I change `w1` or `w2` to be 1x1 instances of a `MatrixSymbol`.

What am I doing wrong here? This is my first time using sympy so I'm very clear that I may just be missing something.

Comment: There are no method or Class in Sympy named `MatrixExp`. There exists class `MatrixExpr`, but it is SuperClass for Matrix Expressions.

Comment: Sorry, MatrixExpr is what I precisely what I meant

Comment: So, as was mentioned, `MatrixExpr` is the SuperClass for Matrix Classes. It just represents abstract matrices. You are not supposed to use it.

Comment: Okay, I'll edit the question to reflect that; using just the result of the sympify call on an expression string also doesn't do what I want or would expect

Comment: Ok, and your first block of code gives a symmetric matrix as a result. Is it gives the correct result?

Comment: @VadimShkaberda: Yes, if the expression is explicitly defined in code it works, however my question is about substituting MatrixSymbols in an expression derived from a string (e.g `exp=sympify('x**2 + 3*x'))`, which doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's look what's going on in simpler case:

```
exp = sympify('w1*X1'); right_exp = w1*X1

type(exp), type(right_exp)
Out[47]: (sympy.core.mul.Mul, sympy.matrices.expressions.matmul.MatMul)
```

Looks like `simpify` doesn'y understand that `X1` is a matrix. So, if we mention it explicit, everything will be allright:

```
exp = sympify("w1*MatrixSymbol('X1',4,4)")

exp.subs([(w1,0.5),(X1,x_1)]).as_explicit()
Out[49]: 
Matrix([
[  0, 0.5,   0,   0],
[0.5,   0,   0,   0],
[  0,   0,   0, 0.5],
[  0,   0, 0.5,   0]])

right_exp.subs([(w1,0.5),(X1,x_1)]).as_explicit()
Out[50]: 
Matrix([
[  0, 0.5,   0,   0],
[0.5,   0,   0,   0],
[  0,   0,   0, 0.5],
[  0,   0, 0.5,   0]])
```

And the final statement:

```
exp = sympify("w1*MatrixSymbol('X1',4,4)+w2*MatrixSymbol('X2',4,4)")

exp.subs([(w1,0.5),(w2,2),(X1,x_1),(X2,x_2)]).as_explicit()
Out[63]: 
Matrix([
[  0, 0.5,   2,   0],
[0.5,   0,   0,   2],
[  2,   0,   0, 0.5],
[  0,   2, 0.5,   0]])
```

What's going on? If you read [Basics of expressions in SymPy](http://mattpap.github.io/scipy-2011-tutorial/html/basics.html#basics-of-expressions-in-sympy) you can find there statement that "matrices aren’t sympifiable" and `simpify` interprets `X1` as a symbol.
It's hard to say how to behave in another situations. There are notes in [docs](http://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/core.html#module-sympy.core.sympify) that warn:

> Sometimes autosimplification during sympification results in
>   expressions that are very different in structure than what was
>   entered.